# determining throughput speed Cordova bridge. Any insights?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to get an idea about the throughput speed of Cordova's `WebView-Native` bridge. For this I will send a `Uint8Array` of a determined size. However, I would have expected the throughput speed of this bridge to be higher.

Testing on a iPhone 4s and Cordova 5.4.1 the throughput speed is  **~0.8mb/s**. This feels low to me (based on some experience with Cordva apps, but this is of course subjective).

Question: is this realistic?

**I think that without posting my code this questions show no enough info, therefore I've attached my code:**

*My JavaScript code:*

```
var success = function(endTime) {
    //endTime is unix epoch time (ms)
    var time_df = endTime - beginTime
    results.push(time_df)
    numTests += 1;
    sendMessage()
}

var sendMessage = function() {
    // execute test 30 times
    if (numTests < 30) {
        beginTime = +new Date()
        bench.send(payload, success, fail)
    } else {
        console.log('results', results)
    }
}
var createPayload = function(size) {
    size = size * 1000;
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(size);
    for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        bufView[i] = i % 20;
    }
    return bufView.buffer;
}

var startTest = function() {
    // create payload of 500kb
    payload = createPayload(500)
    sendMessage()
}
```

*My Objective-C code*.
Code does basicly one thing: return unix epoch time after payload is received.

```
(void)send:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{

   NSTimeInterval time = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]); // returned as a double
   long digits = (long)time; // this is the first 10 digits
   int decimalDigits = (int)(fmod(time, 1) * 1000); // this will get the 3 missing digits
   long timestamp = (digits * 1000) + decimalDigits;
   NSString *timestampString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%d",digits ,decimalDigits];


   NSString* callbackId = [command callbackId];


   CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult
                               resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK
                               messageAsString:timestampString];

    [self success:result callbackId:callbackId];
}
```